# expoert Excel data to web to fill up information

Tags: python

I want to import the data from excel to a web dialog to fill up some information, what is the best way to do it? will Python be the best solution to do it? What sort of library should I use or could you please show me the sample code. Many thanks![image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use xlrd to read content of that excel. Here is instruction for it.
https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966

Then you can use mechanize to fill the web dialog and submit. Here is instruction for it.
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

You should try by yourself and if you encounter some problems then, come back to SO and ask again.